# Will the Dawnguard still give me quests as a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I want to know this because I spontaneously turned into a vampire but the Dawnguard still gives me quests?  I dislike being a vampire and want to be a werewolf.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can still join them as a werewolf.

The [Dawnguard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard_(faction)), as an organization, are completely dedicated to hunting down vampires. Being a werewolf doesn't matter to them in the slightest. As long as you're not a vampire, they're okay with you joining up.

You will, of course, need to not have joined up with the [Volkihar Clan](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Volkihar_Vampire_Clan) in the [Bloodline](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bloodline) quest. If you've outright sided with their enemies, they're not very forgiving, and will still consider you the vampires' ally, even if you get yourself cured of vampirism.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you are a vampire it depends how you became one. If you became a vampire during the quest where you had to choose between the vampire and the dawnguard then they will be forever hostile to you. If you become a vampire later they will be hostile to you but if you cure yourself of vampirism (by becoming a werewolf for example) they won't be hostile to you any more and you can take quests from them again.
And they never care at all whether you're a werewolf or not.
Note: more information here http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard_(faction)

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely I had a conversation with Isran while in werewolf form, he didn't even react when my character reverted in the middle of it